# getting error when i try to use switch button is differen class

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

So I defined a switch button in ProfileSettingsfragment but i am using that button in Explanation.class. What I am really trying to do is when switch button is checked i want start service else i don't  want to star service from Explanation.class
SO I tried Some code and it showing me this error " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat.isChecked()' on a null object reference
at com.harsh.preacher.ui.Home.Explaination$1.onClick(Explaination.java:43)"
P.S I have designed switch  button in ProfileSettingsfragment.xml

Here is ProfileSettingsfragment class code

```
public class ProfileSettingsFragment extends Fragment {
   private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
   public SwitchCompat notePopUp;
   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profilesettings, container, false);
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), gso);
        final ProfileSettingsFragment profileSettingsFragment =new ProfileSettingsFragment();
        Button signOut1 = root.findViewById(R.id.signOut);
        signOut1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //TODO Custom Alert Dialog Bar
//                signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AndarAwoo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
//                Animation(signOut1);
            }
        });
        notePopUp = (SwitchCompat) root.findViewById(R.id.notePopUp);
        RelativeLayout EditName = root.findViewById(R.id.EditName);
        RelativeLayout ProfileSettingsLayout= root.findViewById(R.id.profileSettingsCardView);
        TextView EditNameText = root.findViewById(R.id.EditNameText);
        EditNameText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(EditName.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ProfileSettingsLayout,new AutoTransition());
                    EditName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }else {
                    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(ProfileSettingsLayout,new AutoTransition());
                    EditName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }
        });
        return root;
    }
```

Here is my explanation class code

```
public  class Explaination extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explaination);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String about = intent.getStringExtra("about");
        TextView about1 = findViewById(R.id.about);
        about1.setText(about);

        Button resource = findViewById(R.id.Resource);
        resource.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String url = intent.getStringExtra("button");
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                ProfileSettingsFragment checkNotePopUp = new ProfileSettingsFragment();
                checkNotePopUp.notePopUp = findViewById(R.id.notePopUp);
                if(checkNotePopUp.notePopUp.isChecked()){
                    startService(new Intent(Explaination.this, NotePopUpHead.class));
                }
                else{
                    stopService(new Intent(Explaination.this,NotePopUpHead.class));
                }

                finish();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    }

}
```